# Executenonquery have -1 when i execute a statement

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to fetch rows from a table and insert them into another table. For that I have written this simple code but I am not able to figure out what is the issue.

As you can see I have used `ExecuteNonQuery` after executing my statement and then used messagebox to see the output but the output in message box is -1

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select exp_date from tbl_expences where exp_id='" + i + "'", con);

    int j = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(j));

    if (j > 1)
    {
       string date = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

       MessageBox.Show(date);
       SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update other_expensive set exp_date='" + date + "' where exp_id='" + i + "'", con);
    }
}
```

Comment: The return value of `.ExecuteNonQuery()` is the **number of rows affected** by a `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` operation. Since your `SELECT` doesn't affect any rows --> the value is not defined and is returned as -1. That's by design [and it's documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) for everyone to see. Check MSDN if you need to know something like this first!

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` is used for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. Use `ExecuteReader()` if you want to use `SELECT`.

Comment: now i changed
    int j = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
by
    int j = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteReader());

and I am having an exception 

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: `ExecuteReader` returns an `SqlDataReader`. Have a look in the msdn how it works.

Comment: Can you explain precisely what you are trying to acheive?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you run 20 (possibly 30, depending on what else happens in this code) statements for this?

From the documentation of [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1**. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

(Emphasis added)

Why not just:

```
update oe set exp_date=e.exp_date
from
    other_expensive oe
       inner join
    tbl_expense e
       on
          oe.exp_id = e.exp_id
where
    e.exp_id between 1 and 10
```

Which will do all of the updates in parallel, using one query, and avoid the loop, and the "step-by-step" approach you seem to be trying to use.